# Finding the interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to find the interval of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {{n^2}{x^n}}{2^n}$$
I have deduced that the radius of convergence is $1$, but am unsure of how to then evaluate the series at $x = -1$ and $x = 1$ to find the interval of convergence. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just as a comment, notice that the result of the summation is just 2 x (x - 2) / (2 + x)^3

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite correct: The radius of convergence is $2$, not $1$. To see this, apply the ratio test:

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| &= \frac{(n + 1)^2 x^{n + 1} / 2^{n + 1}}{n^2 x^n / 2^n} \\
&= \frac{(n + 1)^2 x}{2n^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right) \frac{x}{2}
\end{align*}

Now take a limit as $n \to \infty$.

---

Now if $x = \pm 2$, our series is

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n^2(\pm 2)^n}{2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\mp1)^n n^2$$

The sequence terms do not converge to $0$, and the sum is divergent in either case.

Comment: That certainly simplifies things, thank you. Stupid mistake on my part, on my paper I had left out the /2.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know whether $\sum (-1)^n \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ (plugging in x=1) and $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ (plugging in x=-1) converge or diverge.  You can use the alternating series test on the former and some sort of comparison test for the latter (whichever you are familiar with).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the root test to find the radius of convergence. For the special cases, check [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).